# Is there a way to sync the calendar view from a task list into Outlook 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've created a task list for the purpose (hopefully) of becoming a leave request system for the company I work for. Currently they handle requests through paper, and there's a poor handling of that situation.

What I'm trying to do, is take that calendar, and sync it into Outlook 2016 as a shared folder, that way when someone submits vacation or they're out sick, it will sync to the outlook folder and everyone can see who is off for any given day. I know you can sync a calendar if you specifically use the calendar web app, but syncing the task list only syncs the tasks themselves. I'm hoping that calendar view it has can be synced as well, whether out of the box, or even through code.

I'm using SP online and outlook 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Only the items in SharePoint Calendar will be synced to Outlook Calendar.

The tasks synced from a SharePoint task list will be added to the Outlook Tasks.

As a workaround, you can use a Calendar instead.

Or, an idea, use a workflow or remote event receiver on the task list, create the events in a SharePoint Calendar based on the task in the task list. Sync the SharePoint Calendar to Outlook.